# C++ LinkedList Recursion function: Remove first element if value is found in list

Tags: c++, class, recursion, linked-list

Function I'm attempting to write:
bool LinkedList::removeFirst(Node *node, int v);

If v is found in the list, return true and remove the first element of the list. If v is not in the list, return false.

My attempt at the solution:

```html
bool LinkedList::removeFirst(Node *node, int v) {
    if(h==NULL)
      return false;
    if(h->value==v) 
      return true;
    else {
      bool result = findNum(h->next,v);
      if(result == true){
        Node *n = node;
        free(n);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

I understand that my current solution will remove every node in the list, but I can't think of a way to only remove the first in a recursive implementation.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the absolute first element of the list, or the first occurrence of the value `v`?

Comment: Also, with the current interface of the function `removeFirst`, if you actually end up removing the very first element, you will lose your list, because there is no way to modify the pointer to the first element of the list that is held externally. To do that, you must show us the relevant part of the class `LinkedList`, or modify the function to accept a pointer to pointer or something like that.

Comment: OH I JUST REALIZED MY MISTAKE, the function requires you to remove the first node with the instance of value v. I was under the impression that you had to remove the absolute first element of the list. I know how to go from here, thanks for the help!

Comment: My second comment still stands, though. You have a problem in your function signature. You are either taking/returning too much, or not enough.

Comment: The linkedlist class has one pointer to the first Node called "head". So if the node with value v happens to be the first element, I would have to reassign head to the second element to avoid losing the list?

Comment: Yes. But then, you needn't take the node pointer in the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
bool LinkedList::removeFirst (int v)
{
    return removeFirstInSublist (&head, v);
}

bool LinkedList::removeFirstInSublist (Node ** node, int v)
{
    if (!node || !*node) return false;

    Node * p = *node;
    if (v == p->value)
    {
        *node = p->next;
        delete p;  // or free(p);
        return true;
    }

    Node * q = p->next;
    bool b = removeFirstInSublist (&q, v);
    if (q != p->next)
        p->next = q;  // This is the line that actually removes the node from the list.
    return b;
}
```

I believe this will work (but be warned that I haven't tried it.) Basically, the `removeFirstInSublist` method does the work, and we need to take a pointer to pointer because we need to return the address of the node that replaced the one we passed in if we did end up removing it. The `removeFirst` method just calls the actual function with the correct value.

You can choose to make the sublist method private or leave it public, but obviously the interface is a little clunky. I choose pointer to pointer instead of a more friendly reference to pointer because (should you choose to make it public) I wanted the user to know that the pointer they pass in might get changed.